# How to use Angular-UI bootstrap typehead?

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to get started with Angular UI bootstrap.

I have the example running, but I have no idea where to go from here. There isn't much ion the way of documentation or examples.

The documentation for twitter Bootstrap says that typehead has options such as minLength. How do I set that for example? How would I hook it up to a controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, the unit tests file had an example.

```
    <input type="text" ng-model="selected" typehead="state for state in states" typeahead-min-length='3' >
```